# Cakephp change the order of virtualFieldId in find/paginate

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a model in which I have defined a virtualfield, virtualfield01. And when I call a find function like this.

```
$this->myModel->find('all', array(
      'fields' => array(
               'field01',
               'virtualfield01',
               'field02',
               'field03')));
```

the result always gives me.

```
myModel=>array(
       'field01' => 'value01'
       'field02' => 'value02'
       'field03' => 'value03'
       'virtualfield01' => 'virtualvalue01')
```

the virtualfield is always output as the last field of the result.

How can I make the order exactly the same to that I make in the find function???

Comment: what in the model should it order by?

Comment: why do you care? the order should not matter. you can output it any other order you want to in the view.

Comment: I agree with Mark, it doesn't matter in what order the model fetches the field. Whatever way suits the DBO to retrieve the results in the shortest possible time should do. You can still present it however you want in the view.

Comment: coz' I want to pass the output result directly, without re-arrangement action, to the view, and show it by $this->Html->tableCells.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just do something like the following in your view, just as @mark mentioned?

```
$this->Html->tableCells(array(
    $var['Model']['field01'],
    $var['Model']['virtualfield01'],
    $var['Model']['field02'],
    $var['Model']['field03'],
));
```

There's no 're-arrangement action', you're just telling the data how to display, which is why it is a 'view'.

Answer (score 0):

Simple is that as mark Mentioned. Order doesn't matter.